# different documents fields returned with fq parameter

Tags: solr

I am searching on Solr Server indexed & configured by other person.

I am getting different document fields when changing the fq parameter.

On searching,

q=Business Management

fq=type:Insitute

```
returns different document fields on searching the following and above
```

q=Business Management

fq=type:Courses

I could not figure out the reason.

Kindly Advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What request handler are you using ?? with what fl parameter ??
Solr would return all the fields marked as stored and specified by the fl parameter.

[fl parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl) by default returns all the fields for the document.
However, the fields needs to have the values.
So if some of the documents have values for some fields and not others, these fields would not be returned with your query and that's why you may be seeing a difference in the fields returned for the queries depending upon the documents and the fields with values in it.

Comment: Just to know, did you find something wrong or not clear in my answer? Did your answer add something to mine?

Comment: Hi @javanna, Sorry to provide an alternate answer. Your answer was all valid, I just mentioned the condition that the field is not returned if it does not have a value in it more clearly.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry, no problem at all, I just wanted to check with you what wasn't clear in my answer. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Solr returns the stored fields you have within the documents that match the query. You can filter those fields through the [`fl`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl) parameter, but it doesn't seem you're using it from your question. You could check if you have a specific `fl` default parameter in your `solrconfig.xml`, anyway this would work for every document.

Check what you have inside the `fields` element in your `schema.xml`. Some of the fields should have the attribute `required=true`. This means they are required for every document and Solr doesn't accept a document without a value for them. Those required fields are the only fields you must always have back from Solr, while you don't know how many of your documents have an optional field filled in or not. I guess if you filter through `fq` you receive different documents, which don't have the same optional fields filled in.